# How to show VS Code extension version number in welcome view?

Tags: vscode-extensions

My VS Code extension has a tab, which shows a view (defined in `package.json`). Is it possible to show the extension's installed version number (as listed in `package.json`) inside a view?

Specifically I aim to use `viewsWelcome`.

**This is a sample of my code**

I included the `[installed_package_version]` variable as aim for this question.

```
"contributes": {
    "viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "myview",
          "title": "My view",
          "icon": "icon.png"
        }
      ]
    },
    "viewsWelcome": [
      {
        "view": "myview-page",
        "contents": "My content. [My Button](command:my-command) Current version: [installed_package_version]",
        "when": "true"
      }
    ],
    "views": {
      "myview": [
        {
          "id": "myview-page",
          "name": "My view",
          "type": "tree"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: @starball I can get the version number, but how do I send a variable to a view created in `package.json`?

Comment: What do you mean by view provider? As far as I remember, the code above adds a new tab on the left sidebar and opens the view when clicking on it

Comment: @starball I used `viewsWelcome`  https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.viewsWelcome

Comment: @starball Good question. Initially yes because it is simple and offers me what I need for now. Unless showing a variable / version number is not possible this way. I might switch to HTML or another view type. Which one do you suggest?

I only show some text, and a couple of buttons linking to commands. So far the welcome view was working perfectly for this situation using MarkDown syntax and `command:` for links

Answer (score -2):

Here's simple example for how you show vscode extention version in web view:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    // Get the extension's version
    const extensionVersion = vscode.extensions.getExtension('<your_extension_id>').packageJSON.version;

    // Create and show a webview
    const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
        'extensionVersion', // Identifies the type of the webview. Used internally
        'Extension Version', // Title of the panel displayed to the user
        vscode.ViewColumn.One, // Editor column to show the new webview panel in
        {}
    );

    // Set the HTML content of the webview
    panel.webview.html = getWebViewContent(extensionVersion);
}

function getWebViewContent(version: string): string {
    return `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Extension Version</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Extension Version</h1>
            <p>The installed version of the extension is: ${version}</p>
        </body>
        </html>
    `;
}
```

if this helped?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you also know how to add buttons linking to VSCode commands for web views?

Currently in my view I use `[My command](command:my-extension.my-command)`

Comment: This creates a new page, not a view displayed when clicking my sidebar tab icon. I want to find a solution where I can see the version in my view please

Comment: I smell AI generated content.